# best way to process large data in chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have like for example more then 20000 records . and data is something like this

```
data = [{'id': 1} , {'id':2} , {'id':3} .... 20000]
```

now I want to upload this data in chunks of 1000 . so what is best way to do this in 1000 chunk which will give least overhead .

Comment: What do you mean by upload?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use generators. These are generic iterators that allow you traverse objects using custom behaviours.

In your case, an easy solution is to use `range` which returns a generator of any specific size, for example:

```
range(1, len(data), 1000)
```

Will generate the values 1, 1001, 2001, ...

If you use that in a loop, you can then pass the specific range to a handler method, for example:

```
batch = 1000
for i in range(1, len(data), batch):
  handle(data[i:i+batch])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generators to process the data in batches

```
def generateChunks(data,    batchsize):
  for i in range(0, len(data),batchsize):
    yield data[i:i+batchsize]
```

Process data

```
chunks = generateChunks(data, 1000)
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
  print('chunk# ', i ,': ', chunk)
```